# One to one mapping of Java Thread to Linux thread (LWP)

Tags: java, linux, multithreading

Is there a one to one mapping between Java `Thread` objects and OS threads (Lightweight processes). That is, if I have a `Thread` object, can I always identify precisely one associated OS thread, and will I always have the same associated OS thread? In general this is OS and JVM dependent,  so I'll restrict the question to Linux with the Oracle and Open JDK JVMs.

What about the cases of `sleep`ing or `wait`ing threads?  And the corner cases of threads that have not started running and those that have finished running?

Comment: Linux does not really have "LWP"s; all execution threads are a result of calling `clone(2)` with different parameters

Comment: re "can I always identify precisely one associated OS thread" the answer is yes; otherwise `Thread` guarantees could not be honored (think about thread local storage)

Comment: Java `Thread`s can be , and have been (green threads) implemented without OS threads, so OS threads are not necessary to provide the `Thread` guarantees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a one to one mapping between Java Thread objects and OS threads (

Yes there is, it has been since Java 1.2.

Prior to Java 1.2 a "green threads" model were used which mapped several Java threads to one OS thread.

Comment: You certainly could run the JVM with green threads on linux back in the day.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: AFAIK also on Linux, because the early threading-model on Linux itself was not based on POSIX threads but ... something else with quite heavy setup costs.

Comment: See also this answer to a related question:   http://stackoverflow.com/a/8569625/545127

Comment: See also this answer to a related question:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/9934747/545127