# Is X threads implemented via X processes?

Tags: linux, windows, multithreading, process, operating-system

I know that there is multithreading vs multiprocessing approach.
But I was under the impression that threads are implemented as processes by the OS. So the threading model is just a programming construct on top of processes.
At least in Java (hence the tag although this question is language agnostic) I know that the threads are implemented by the linux as processes 
Is it not the general case? Does it depend on the OS?

**UPDATE** for Java asked in comment by @SotiriosDelimanolis: [One to one mapping of Java Thread to Linux thread (LWP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17125101/one-to-one-mapping-of-java-thread-to-linux-thread-lwp)

Comment: _I know that the threads are implemented by the linux as processes._ How do you know this?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis:I have read it in the past that they are implemented as lwp processes.I can look up a reference if you want

Comment: In Windows, threads are not implemented as processes.

Comment: @HarryJohnston:Then how?

Comment: In Windows, processes are higher-level constructs that encompass the runtime environment: code, data memory-management, working-set, security permissions etc.   The basic unit of execution is a thread, which requires a stack.  All processes require at least one thread, and the OS loader creates it at process startup to run the code at the executable entry point.  That thread is free to create more threads that become a part of the process resources.

Comment: @Jim: what do you mean, "then how" ?  Threads are implemented as threads.  Each thread belongs to a process.

Answer (score 1):

Threads in modern versions of Java are "native" and are implemented, scheduled and handled by the OS the JVM is running on.  So the answer depends on which OS you are using.

[Distinguishing between Java threads and OS threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888160/distinguish-java-threads-and-os-threads)

**EDIT**

In general, not just java, the rules for how threads are created is determined by the language, the OS and and language libraries that are used (or some combination of those).

But in general, on modern OSes, multiple threads often share a single process for performance reasons.  Threads are sometimes called *light weight processes*.

[This link](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node29.html) has an overview of threads and C libraries for writing multithreaded apps for various OSes.

Comment: What does the term native mean?Also please note that this question is not specific to Java.Unless you are trying to say that the thread implementation depends both in the OS *and* the language

Comment: native means ...um..."locally born". In this context a native thread is something that the OS creates

Comment: Yes but does that mean that this is an implementation detail and the OS could create processes or via some other way?

Comment: @Jim depends on the language.  Something higher level like Java - it's an implementation detail.  Something lower level, you might have more control